# How can I used trained network in .net

Tags: matlab, neural-network

Hi I trained my network into Matlab neural network toolbox I save it.. I can used into matlab environment by calling sim(net,p) but How can I export it to anther .net apps ?

Comment: asp.net VB.net I wanna built as web apps... Any ideas plz ?

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off exporting just the `weights` (etc.) element of the network and using them in a library designed for .NET like [AForge.NET](http://code.google.com/p/aforge/), rather than deal with all of the interop.

Comment: @user769027 For the actual interop, see the following questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/434331/interoperating-between-matlab-and-c, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226631/c-matlab-interoperability-for-non-matrix-datatypes, but I still think once you've trained the network, you can transfer the weight matrices either into a C#-based neural network, or used directly.